# Access query distinct record when all rows same

Tags: ms-access, select, distinct

Not sure how to properly phrase question/description, so will ask by example.

In Access, I need to run a query to return one record, if all rows of (2 column) select distinct are the same.

So:

Style   |   Flag

123     |   Y

123     |   N

123     |   Y

456     |   Y

456     |   Y

456     |   Y

789     |   N

789     |   N

789     |   N

I would only want to return 456 once because all versions of '456' style have a flag = 'Y'. Style '123' would not be returned because it's mixed 'Y' AND 'N'. Style '789' should not be returned because all instances are 'N'. I am only trying to return the "all 'Y', only 'Y' records"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the query into 3 parts

Part 1, Group by Style and Flag (Count rows for information) Save this as Query1

```
SELECT Table1.Style, Table1.Flag, Count(Table1.ID) AS CountOfID
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.Style, Table1.Flag;
```

Part 2 - Group by Style, and count number of Flag records, then filter to show only records with a flag count of 1.  Save this as Query2

```
SELECT Query1.Style, Count(Query1.Flag) AS CountOfFlag
FROM Query1
GROUP BY Query1.Style
HAVING (((Count(Query1.Flag))=1));
```

Part 3 - Join back to the original table, and filter to show only Styles with a Y flag.

```
SELECT Table1.Style, Table1.Flag
FROM Query2 INNER JOIN Table1 ON Query2.Style = Table1.Style
GROUP BY Table1.Style, Table1.Flag
HAVING (((Table1.Flag)="Y"));
```

(Table1, Query1, Query2, Query3 Names can be replaced with something more meaningful to your problem set).

Comment: Thanks - this works, but gives me more data than I need in the results set. I failed to include more sample data to illustrate my point/question.

If you add a third style to the mix, that only has a flag set to "N", that would be returned in the results set as well. I would want to filter those records out - only show where all same, and all = "Y". So:
789  |  N
789  |  N
789  |  N
would show in the current state, but I need to filter those out. Where would I put the conditional to only look for Style="Y"?